# Memory leak in C, 2d array in struct

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free, realloc

I really need some help with memory leaks. Ive been staring at my code for a while and still cant find out where are those leaks. I think I am freeing everything, even sometimes unnecessarily, but there is still something.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Matrix{
    int **data;
    int rows;
    int columns;
};

struct Matrix matrix_op(struct Matrix, struct Matrix, char);
int** _2d_array(int,int);
void print_matrix(struct Matrix);
void _2d_array_free(int**, int);
void _scalar_mul(struct Matrix*, int);

int** _2d_array(int x,int y){
    int** arr;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int*)*x);
    for(int i = 0; i<x;++i){
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*y);
    }
    return arr;
}
void _scalar_mul(struct Matrix* a, int s){
    for (int x = 0; x < a->rows; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < a->columns; ++y)
            a->data[x][y] *= s;
    }
}

void _2d_array_free(int** array, int x){
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}

void exit_err(int err, char* message){
    fprintf(stderr,message);
    exit(err);
}

struct Matrix read_matrix(int x, int y){
    struct Matrix matrix;
    matrix.rows = x;
    matrix.columns = y;
    matrix.data = _2d_array(x,y);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
            if(scanf("%d", &matrix.data[i][j])==0) exit_err(100,"Error...\n");
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

struct Matrix matrix_op(struct Matrix a, struct Matrix b, char op) {
    struct Matrix res_matrix;
    int** result;
    if (op == '*') {
        if(a.columns==b.rows) {
            result = _2d_array(a.rows, b.columns);
            for (int x = 0; x < a.rows; ++x) {
                for (int y = 0; y < b.columns; ++y) {
                    int sum = 0;
                    for (int z = 0; z < a.columns; z++) {
                        sum += a.data[x][z] * b.data[z][y];
                    }
                    result[x][y] = sum;
                }
            }
        }
        else exit_err(100,"Error...\n");
        res_matrix.data = result;
        res_matrix.rows = a.rows;
        res_matrix.columns = b.columns;
    } else {
        if (op == '-') {
            _scalar_mul(&b,-1);
        }
        result = _2d_array(a.rows,a.columns);
        for (int x = 0; x < a.rows; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < a.columns; ++y){
                result[x][y]=a.data[x][y]+b.data[x][y];
            }
        }
        res_matrix.data = result;
        res_matrix.rows = a.rows;
        res_matrix.columns = a.columns;
    }
    return res_matrix;
}

void print_matrix(struct Matrix matrix){
    printf("%d %d\n",matrix.rows, matrix.columns);
    for(int x = 0; x<matrix.rows;++x){
        for(int y = 0; y<matrix.columns;++y){
            if(y==0)printf("%d", matrix.data[x][y]);
            else printf(" %d",matrix.data[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int x,y,count;
    count=0;
    char op='\0';
    struct Matrix* matrices = malloc(0);
    while(1){
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        matrices = realloc(matrices,sizeof(struct Matrix)*(++count));
        matrices[count-1]=read_matrix(x,y);
        if(op=='-') {
            _scalar_mul(&matrices[count - 1], -1);
        };
        if(op=='*') {
            struct Matrix result = matrix_op(matrices[count-2], matrices[count-1], op);
            _2d_array_free(matrices[count-1].data, matrices[count-1].rows);
            matrices[count-1] = result;
            _2d_array_free(matrices[count-2].data, matrices[count-2].rows);
            matrices[count-2].rows=0;
        }
        if(scanf("\n%c", &op)==EOF) break;

    }
    struct Matrix res;
    res.data = _2d_array(3,3);
    res.rows = 3;
    res.columns = 3;
    res = matrices[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
        if(res.rows>0&&matrices[i].rows>0) {
            struct Matrix tmp = matrix_op(res, matrices[i], '+');
            _2d_array_free(res.data, res.rows);
            res.rows = 0;
            res = tmp;
        }
        else if (res.rows==0){
            _2d_array_free(res.data, res.rows);
            res.rows = 0;
            res = matrices[i];
        }
    }
    print_matrix(res);
    _2d_array_free(res.data, res.rows);
    for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
        if(matrices[j].rows!=0){
            _2d_array_free(matrices[j].data,matrices[j].rows);
        }
    }
    free(matrices);
}
```

**Valgrind out:**

```
==25== Invalid read of size 8
==25==    at 0x4008B5: _2d_array_free (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x401038: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==  Address 0x51fc0d0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==25==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==25==    by 0x4008D7: _2d_array_free (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400F51: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==  Block was alloc'd at
==25==    at 0x4C2AC3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==25==    by 0x4007AC: _2d_array (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400936: read_matrix (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400D46: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==
==25== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==25==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==25==    by 0x4008BF: _2d_array_free (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x401038: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==  Address 0x51fc130 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 28 free'd
==25==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==25==    by 0x4008BF: _2d_array_free (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400F51: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==  Block was alloc'd at
==25==    at 0x4C2AC3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==25==    by 0x4007DF: _2d_array (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400936: read_matrix (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400D46: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==
==25== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==25==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==25==    by 0x4008D7: _2d_array_free (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x401038: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==  Address 0x51fc0d0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==25==    at 0x4C2BD57: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==25==    by 0x4008D7: _2d_array_free (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400F51: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==  Block was alloc'd at
==25==    at 0x4C2AC3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==25==    by 0x4007AC: _2d_array (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400936: read_matrix (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==    by 0x400D46: main (in /mnt/c/Users/wM/ClionProjects/hw4/main)
==25==
==25==
==25== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25==     in use at exit: 60 bytes in 4 blocks
==25==   total heap usage: 19 allocs, 19 frees, 432 bytes allocated
==25==
==25== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==25==    indirectly lost: 36 bytes in 3 blocks
==25==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==25==
==25== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Input**

```
3 7
-42 8 -62 0 7 46 3
7 11 45 89 -39 -27 70
-35 -5 0 -99 -50 -14 46
+
3 7
73 -88 -45 94 -41 -67 -66
0 22 30 29 72 -91 76
-95 -83 -46 -88 28 69 -62
```

**Output**

```
3 7
31 -80 -107 94 -34 -21 -63
7 33 75 118 33 -118 146
-130 -88 -46 -187 -22 55 -16
```

Output is ok, but the memory leak and valgrind errors are undesirable.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak? When and where and how do you allocate memory? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also include your input, and the expected and actual output in the question.

Comment: My C is a bit rusty, but I think `free(array[i])` only frees that first array item, not the entire array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is this:

```
struct Matrix res;
res.data = _2d_array(3,3);
res.rows = 3;
res.columns = 3;
res = matrices[0];
```

You define `res` and initialize it, then you *reassign* it with `matrices[0]` which overwrite all the data you previously initialized, including the pointer to the data you just allocated.

---

Also:

```
_2d_array_free(res.data, res.rows);
for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
    if(matrices[j].rows!=0){
        _2d_array_free(matrices[j].data,matrices[j].rows);
    }
}
```

Here `res.data` points to some data allocated for one of the entries in `matrices`, so you are attempting to free the data twice which is wrong. The simple solution to this is to not call `_2d_array_free` for `res.data`.

---

Lastly a little note about style and naming: You should really avoid using symbol-names with leading underscores. If you're not careful you might use a reserved symbol (underscore followed by an upper-case letter or another underscore). Leading underscores are usually used internally by the compiler and standard library.